# Android EditText background changes when soft keyboard shown

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText that I set to white text on a black background using

```
et.setBackgroundColor(rgb(0, 0, 0));
et.setTextColor(rgb(255,255,255));
```

When I click the text the soft keyboard appears as normal but the background changes to white.  So the text is white on a white background.  Not very helpful when trying to edit it.

How can I get the background to remain black when the soft keyboard is visible?

If I use the third party "Hackers Keyboard" the background color is maintained so the Android soft keyboard is resetting the background color somehow?

After more testing this only seems to occur on a Samsung Galaxy Note 5 and it also happens in the Android Studio emulator for SDK 21.  A Samsung Galaxy Tab S and other physical test devices do not show the issue so far.  Really strange.

Comment: Is it an option to just set the Theme background to black? Like adding `<item name="android:windowBackground">#000000</item>` to your Themes' style in your styles.xml?

Comment: Good idea, but no go.  The edittext background still turns white.  If I have mutlicolor text the text colors all remain fine when the keyboard appears.  Only the background color is not kept and forced to white.